# PDF creation with images, extracted from another PDF, using PDFBox way too slow and created PDF size is way larger than the original PDF

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

I have been developing an app which takes a PDF and then it strips down all its images and stores them as ArrayList of bitmaps. These bitmaps can then further be edited and then saved as PDF. When I am trying to save them as PDF after editing or just without editing the PDF size becomes ten times the original PDF size and though I have made each page processing on a different thread it stills runs very slow.

*for example:*  If I take a PDF of size 28 MB it takes somewhere in the neighborhood of 4 minutes to make them back into PDF. There are 20 images in the PDF and the output PDF size is above 200 MB.

I am using the PDFBox library from Tom Roush for android. [Tom Roush PDFBox Repo](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android).

This is the createPdf() method :

```
public void createPdf() {
        document = new PDDocument();

            for(Bitmap image : images)
            {
                PDFPages page=new PDFPages();
                page.execute(image);
            }

    }
```

The asynctask PDFPages class is as follows :

```
public class PDFPages extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Integer,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... voids) {

            try {
                Bitmap image=voids[0];
                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                document.addPage(page);
                // Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

                PDImageXObject ximage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, image);

                // Defining and calculating position and scaling variables
                float w = image.getWidth();
                float h = image.getHeight();

                float x_pos = page.getCropBox().getWidth();
                float y_pos = page.getCropBox().getHeight();


                if (w > h) {
                    h = h * (x_pos / w);
                    w = x_pos;
                } else {
                    w = w * (y_pos / h);
                    h = y_pos;
                }

                float x_adjusted = (x_pos - w) / 2;
                float y_adjusted = (y_pos - h) / 2;

                contentStream.drawImage(ximage, x_adjusted, y_adjusted, w, h);

                // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
                contentStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            countPages = countPages + 1;

            if(countPages == images.size()) {
                try {
                    // Save the final pdf document to a file
                    final String path = myDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Created.pdf";

                    document.save(path);
                    document.close();

                    Toast.makeText(process.this, "PDF successfully written to :" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                saving.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                anim.cancel();

            }

        }
    }
```

The method used for extracting images out of the PDF is as follows :

```
public void createImages()
    {
        try {
            //Loading the pdf file
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
            //Getting all the pages in list
            PDPageTree pages= document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
            Iterator iter = pages.iterator();

            myDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "PDF/" + pdfName);
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // i used for counting number of images
            i=0;

            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                PDPage page=(PDPage) iter.next();
                PDResources resources=page.getResources();

                //Tom Roush code that he commented against my issue of not having resources.getImages() method
                for (COSName name : resources.getXObjectNames())
                {
                    PDXObject xobj = resources.getXObject(name);
                    if (xobj instanceof PDImageXObject)
                    {
                        bit = ((PDImageXObject)xobj).getImage();
                        //Image acquired.
                        if(bit != null) {
                            images.add(bit);
                        }
                        i=i+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i == 0)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(process.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("images",i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            document.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("helll","Completed CreateImages()");
    }
```

`images` is the ArrayList of bitmaps.

The input PDF is the PDF made by Cam Scanner (*the app*) with the use of 20 images taken by the device's camera. It has a size of 27.45 MB and the output PDF has a size of 
264.10 MB

*I will upload the PDFs shortly. 
The reason why I can't upload: I am currently away from my workspace and I am entirely dependent on my phone's internet and yes I live in a third world country. So I will upload the PDFs in my google drive and edit in the links as soon as I get some decent internet connection.*

I want some method by which I can lower the time of outputting and the size of the outputted PDF.

Comment: Maybe you didn't use the same filter as in the original PDF. A b/w scan can be stored very efficiently with the ccitt filter but will be bigger with the Flate filter. Hard to tell since you shared nothing. And yes , PDF can be quite efficient when used well.

Comment: What more should I share? I am new to this PDF manipulation world and till now I didn't know about filters, I will definitely look into it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Share the source and the destination PDFs and explain how you got the images. The filter thing is hard to use directly, but you can influence it by choosing the image generation factory.

Comment: While I assume that the main impact is from the choice of the image generation factory (images originally stored as jpegs now are stored losslessly and so take up much more space) some additional impact might be due to the same image used on multiple pages (in the original pdf only a single image object, in the output as many as uses).

Comment: Add an aside, you only grab images from the immediate page resources. There may also be images in the resources of used patterns or form xobjects.

Comment: Thanks, @mkl this was the problem all along and it was solved by replacing LossLess with JPEGFactory. However, I remember thinking about this before and implementing JPEGFactory but it didn't work. It worked now, strange, am I high.

Comment: if the images in the PDF are of the jpeg type (DCTFilter), then you can extract them 1:1: `image.getPDStream().getPartiallyFilteredStream(DCT_FILTERS)`. This is from the 1.8 desktop version, which is (partially) used in PDFBox for Android. If it uses 2.0 API, then call `image.createInputStream(Arrays.asList(COSName.DCT_DECODE.getName()))`

Comment: Beware, though, there might be settings in the image dictionary that override some properties in the JPEG stream. The problem may show as unexpected colors.